# finding a process ID and listing the command name and any network connections

Tags: linux, unix, grep, ps

i've been trying to create a script that will take a process ID number (PID) and then identify the process ID with its name and also list any network connections that its connected to.

I understand I should use netstat to do this. here is my code so far however it doesn't seem to do anything, can you explain where im going wrong and what i need to do?

```
echo 'Please enter a Process ID: '
read pidN
echo 'You entered process ID: ' $pidN

pID= pgrep -fl "^(/.*)?${pidN}\s"
echo $pID
```

Comment: You can `netstat -antep | grep <PID>` on Linux systems.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the command below (ex: ssh)

```
netstat -nalp | grep -i ssh
```

Follow the result:

```
[root@localhost ~]# netstat -nalp | grep 1055
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1055/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1055/sshd
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     20308    1055/sshd
```

Comment: i want to make it so it takes a user input process ID rather than grepping for the process name itself. I know i have to read the user input and make it into a variable, im just struggling to match it with a process and display the process name as well as the network connections